# Mac install MySQL from a shell script

Tags: shell-script, software-installation, osx, mysql

I want to programmatically install MySQL to a Mac system running OS 10.11.6 El Capitan, so once the .dmg has been downloaded the script unpack it with the command:

```
sudo hdiutil attach mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg
```

after that the script runs:

```
sudo installer -package /Volumes/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64 .pkg -target /
```

Here starts the installer, now when I install MySQL from the GUI I get a message-box telling me the temporary password for the root user (see attached picture)

[image]

so, what I want is the script to read the temp root password and eventually set a predefined password for the root user:

1) is possilbe to make bash shell read the temp password and store it into a variable?

2) can the script reset the root password automatically?

Comment: the answers in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169900/117549 may be helpful

Comment: For Apple-specific questions you should know there is a [Stack Exchange site devoted to Apple products](http://apple.stackexchange.com), although for general Bash scripting knowledge this site is a much better fit.  I suspect, though, that there are ways to do this via AppleScript that you will not hear about on this site, but only apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: also possibly - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265327/117549